# Sort by two parameters in Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I want to have my products sorted by two parameters: first by "sort order" that every product has; and then by quantity.

Here is what I have in file /catalog/controller/product/category.php (Opencart 1.5.6.4) and I believe here is what should be somehow changed:

```
if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
    $sort = $this->request->get['sort'];
} else {
    $sort = 'p.sort_order';
}
```

Anyone has any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Opencart only uses a single field at a time for sorting.  To accomplish what you described you'll need to modify the query for the `getProducts()` method which is built in `/catalog/model/catalog/product.php`.  Find line 196 where it reads:

```
$sql .= " ORDER BY p.sort_order";
```

This is the default sort order when none is specified.  To add a secondary sort criteria you can change it to:

```
$sql .= " ORDER BY p.sort_order, p.quantity";
```

If you *always* want to use `quantity` as a secondary sort field, you can add after the entire block like this:

```
    } else {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY p.sort_order";   
    }

    $sql .= ", p.quantity";
```

This would sort by quantity as a secondary field regardless of what primary sort field was specified.